# How to improve Ridge Regression's robustness against collinearity?

Tags: multicollinearity, ridge-regression

I have been working on LASSO for a while and then I realized that dealing with collinearity is really tricky for LASSO, due to the feature selection part.

I have shifted my focus to Ridge, which seems to be most robust to collinearity.

However, I am wondering if there is any other ways to improve ridge regression's robustness against collinearity.

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you please say some more about what you mean by "robustness against collinearity" and the ways in which you find ridge regression deficient in that regard?

Comment: Ridge is already robust to multicollinearity. What sort of extra robustness are you looking for?